# How can I mock a custom callback passport.authenticate(...) method in PassportJS using Jest?

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, passport.js

I'm creating a back-end for a simple project, and I've gotten PassportJS and the Local Strategy to work. I wanted to add some unit tests to my controller but I can't figure out how to mock all of the business logic within my passport.authenticate, which is using a custom callback.

I've already tried using Jest's mockImplementation to create a method or a function but it always gives me a TypeError that says passport.authenticate(...) is not a function.

Here is the "registerUser" operation in my controller that's using PassportJS with a custom callback on a Local Strategy.

```
const registerUser = async (req, res, next) => {
  const userDetails = req.body;
  const userValidation = bodyValidator.register(userDetails);
  if (userValidation.statusCode === undefined) {
    passport.authenticate('localRegister', (err, user, info) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      if (info !== undefined) {
        res.status(400);
        res.send({
          status: 'error',
          message: info.message,
          statusCode: 400,
          code: 400
        });
      } else {
        req.logIn(user, async err => {
          const userData = {
            firstName: userDetails.firstName,
            lastName: userDetails.lastName,
            email: userDetails.email
          };
          await User.update(userData);
          res.status(200);
          res.send({
            message: 'Register successful!'
          });
        });
      }
    })(req, res, next);
  } else {
    res.status(userValidation.statusCode);
    res.send(userValidation);
  }
};
```

And this is what my test case looks like right now, but I don't know how to mock the authenticate method.

*edited to show more code*

```
const userController = require('../userController');
const User = require('../../models/users');
const passport = require('passport');

jest.mock('../../models/users');
jest.mock('passport');

describe.only('Register user succeeds', () => {
  let send = jest.fn();
  let status = jest.fn();
  let next = jest.fn();

  let res = {
    send,
    status
  };

  afterEach(() => {
    send.mockRestore();
    status.mockRestore();
    next.mockRestore();
  });

  it('should send a response', async () => {
    const req = {
      body: {
        email: 'mock@email.com',
        password: 'mockPassword',
        firstName: 'mockFirstName',
        lastName: 'mockLastName'
      },
      logIn
    };
    passport.authenticate.mockImplementation(() => {
      req, res, () => (done(null, '1', undefined))
    });
    User.update.mockReturnValue({});
    await userController.registerUser(req, res, next);
    expect(res.status).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(res.send).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

I get a TypeError: passport.authenticate(...) is not a function, whereas I'm hoping that I can mock the `(err, user, info)` callback arguments from my controller's passport.authenticate()!

Comment: Please provide more code. Did you import `passport` into your test file?

Comment: Hi, added the rest of the code to the test, yup I've imported passport and tried to do jest.mock to it too :)